# How to send multiple FlatList items to another screen in ReactNative?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have this data, i know how to display the data using Flatlist but how can add multi-select functionality?

User can select multiple items and how can i pass the selected items to another screen using props?

```
const goods = [{
        key: 1,
        item: 'Laptops & accessories'
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        item: 'Mobiles & accessories'
    },
    {
        key: 3,
        item: 'Television'
    },
    {
        key: 4,
        item: 'Washing Machine'
    },
    {
        key: 5,
        item: 'Air Conditioners'
    },
    {
        key: 6,
        item: 'Refrigerators'
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add one more field like selected in list as follows and show image accordingly if selected then show checkmark image otherwise show non-checkmark image.

```
const goods = [{
        key: 1,
        item: 'Laptops & accessories',
    selected: false
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        item: 'Mobiles & accessories',
    selected: false
    },
    {
        key: 3,
        item: 'Television',
    selected: false
    },
    {
        key: 4,
        item: 'Washing Machine',
    selected: false
    },
    {
        key: 5,
        item: 'Air Conditioners',
    selected: false
    },
    {
        key: 6,
        item: 'Refrigerators',
    selected: false
    },
]
```

and when select any item, then make it `selected = true` for that particular item. And you can sent that selected items to next screen as props using this

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('screen2', { item });
```

to retrieve at screen2 use following code

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.item;
```